# How to modify a Python submodule's argparse from the main script?

Tags: python, arguments

I wrote a custom submodule to reuse the same code in my similar API projects.

In my submodule, I have the following:

```
# sub.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

arg_parser = ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument("-s", "--silent", help="silent mode", action="store_true")
script_args = arg_parser.parse_args()

if not script_args.silent:
    # If the silent flag isn't passed then add logging.
    #logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

What's the best way to add additional arguments via `add_argument()` in my main script?

```
# main.py
import sub

# This still works:
if sub.script_args.silent:
    # Some code

# I tried this, but it doesn't work:
sub.arg_parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", help="test mode", action="store_true")
sub.script_args.parse_args()
# The script doesn't know about -t.
```

Comment: I would put code in functions - first would return `arg_parser` which has `--silent`, second would  run `parse_args()` - so later you can run in main `arg_parser = first()`, `arg_parser = add_args(arg_parser)` `script_args = second(arg_parser)`

Comment: @furas I don't think that'll work since sub.py does some arg checking before it gets to main.py. Maybe I shouldn't run any import-time code in sub.py...

Comment: you should keep all code in functions so you could run some code in main before you run code which you imported from sub.py

Comment: The most basic idea is that you shouldn't let the submodule to run `arg_parser.parse_args()` or even `arg_parser.parse_known_args()`, the submodule should only define the parser and let the main entry to decide when to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **parse_known_args** function ([partial parsing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing)).

For example:

```
# sub.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

arg_parser = ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument("-s", "--silent", help="silent mode", action="store_true")
partial_script_args = arg_parser.parse_known_args()[0]

print("silent") if partial_script_args.silent else print("not silent")
```

```
# main.py
import sub

# This still works:
if sub.partial_script_args.silent:
    pass

sub.arg_parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", help="test mode", action="store_true")
full_script_args = sub.arg_parser.parse_args()

print("test") if full_script_args.test else print("not test")
```

Note the warning in the documentation:

> **Warning:** [Prefix matching](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations-prefix-matching) rules apply to parse_known_args(). The parser may consume an option even if it’s just a prefix of one of its known options, instead of leaving it in the remaining arguments list.

Comment: That works except the default `-h` or `--help` only list the silent argument, not test. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @hobbes3 This is because the first `parse_args` recognizes  `-h` and prints help without knowing that there are other arguments in other file. `parse_known_args` is usually used for command wrapping or a shared library, so it is a desired behavior. If you just want to do some type checking or such then you should have a better design so the first `parse_args` would already know any argument you want it to know.

Comment: @hobbes3 but if you insist, you can call `ArgumentParser(add_help=False)` in _sub_ so the first `parse_args` would not recognize `-h` or `--help`. Then in _main_ you can define explicitly the help argument (using `add_argument`) and call `sub.arg_parser.print_help()` if the help argument was called. Your _sub_ file should also know if the help argument was called so it won't do unnecessary work (like arg checking) in such case. The second return value of `parse_known_args` is the list of remaining arguments, so _sub_ can look for the help argument in this list.